# Regular expressions: What is the difference between `[0-9]{1,2}` and `^[0-9]{1,2}$`?

Tags: regex

What is the difference between `[0-9]{1,2}` and `^[0-9]{1,2}$`?

If we remove `^` and `$`, what will the effect be in this case?

Comment: Match beginning and end of the string. I think it is self explanatory.

Comment: @webarto, this must be some _new_ definition of the phrase "self explanatory" of which I was previously unaware :-) With apologies to the great Douglas Adams for stealing his phrase. There is _nothing_ in the symbol `^` that indicates start of string (unless it's somehow encoded in the microdots somewhere). Self explanatory usually means that it stands alone without any further input. That's vastly different from having to look up the fact that `^` _means_ start of string. The _definition_ of the character may be self-explanatory but the character itself is not. IMNSHO :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, thank you for making it clear, respect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those characters are called anchors and they bind to specific positions in the string. If you're not discussing multi-line regexes, they will bind to the beginning (for `^`) and end (for `$`) of the string.

That means that `^[0-9]{1,2}$` is a string that consists of exactly one or two digits and nothing else, while `[0-9]{1,2}` is a string of any size containing one or two consecutive digits in it anywhere.

So the first will match `1`, `77`, `96`, `42` and so on. The latter will *also* match any of those with any amount of text on either side, like `paxdiablo is number 1`, `calling car 54, where are you` and so on.

If your regex engine is capable of handling multi-line input, the meaning is usually slightly changed. `^` will bind to either the start of the string or a zero-width point following an end of line character. Similarly, `$` will bind to the end of string and any zero-width point before an end on line.

In those cases, if you want to only match the start or end of the string, you'll probably find you can use `\A` and `\Z`.

Comment: +1 Good answer. But there is one detail about `$` you left out: for many/most Perl style regex flavors (e.g. Perl, PHP, Python - but NOT Javascript), the `$` anchor will match before a newline character at the end of the string, even when multi-line mode is off. So `^[0-9]{1,2}$` will match the string: `"12\n"`.

Answer (score 3):

The `^` means that the match shall appear at the beginning of a string, and the `$` says that it should match the end of a string.

In your case `[0-9]{1,2}` will match any number with one or two digits inside any string (e.g. `sakdj12lkjad92` will match), while the latter one will only match if the string only contains one or two digits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, in the `^[0-9]{1,2}$` case, does that mean it will **only** match strings that look as follows: *1, 34, 56, 2, 10,...etc*?

Answer (score 2):

```
^ means start of string
$ means end of string
```

**[0-9]{1,2}**  => [DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/WOegKxqjbT)

**^[0-9]{1,2}** => [DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/GlNpBhU3t6)